# Python find matching URL for Text String

Tags: python

Alright,

I got following Code working:

```
import re


with open('html.txt') as f:
    urls = f.read()
    links = re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', urls)
for url in links:
    print(url[0].replace("#038;", "")) #Replace is for making invalid URL in a working one
```

HTML Textfile sample:

```
<td class="download-file" data-title="Download">
      <a href="https://URL.com/?download_file=259&#038;order=wc_order_xBxDxBxD&#038;emailtestmail%40gmail.com&#038;key=1234-1234-1234-1234-12345678" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt">
    INSTRUCTION</a>                 

</td>
```

**Problem:**

There are couple of those Links in the HTML.txt File i created.

I also have a List of strings that match the URL Text, example: [Instruction, File2, File3, etc...]

Now I would like to match the strings in the List with the matching URL in my .txt File.

**Basicly I want to create a Second List, that has the URL's of the matching Strings**

However its not important that I have a specific order in the List, I just want to make sure each String in my List [Instruction, File2, File3, etc...] finds his matching URL from the Textfile.

Really struggled alot and cant find a solution, so I really appreciate your help on this matter.

Comment: The output of my List = ['Instruction', 'File2', 'File3', ...]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the BeautifulSoup library to parse HTML files (I would also clarify that it looks like you are parsing a `.html` file, not a `.txt` file.) (Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment.)

Comment: Hey there, initaliy im using BeautifulSoup, its just I couldnt get the HTML-Source AFTER Login... really tried it, didnt work out. thats why i just copy pasted the source in the txt file. Its intentional that im parsing a .txt file in this case.